# How to access a custom table name that isn't prefixed with exp_

Tags: add-on-development, module, database

I'm developing an EE module that needs to access a non EE database table that isn't prefixed with 'exp_'.

How would I go about doing this? In Codeigniter I can use set_dbprefix, but that doesn't appear to be available in EE.

I'm using EE 2.73 currently.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, using the query module (and relative portion of the database class) doesn't force the prefix.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/

So you can use that to query any full table name:

```
$result = ee()->db->query('SELECT * FROM not_prefixed_table')->result_array();
```

You just annoyingly have to write out each query.

**Edit** Also, I'm assuming you don't have permissions to make schema and table changes to this database, because otherwise the obvious answer is just modify the table name to include the prefix.

Comment: Thanks @jrothafer! I do have permission but I have a Codeigniter application that I've written running on the same server and I don't want to change the table names :-)

Comment: I ended up going for this solution as it was the quickest and simplest in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the database to be used like so:

```
$mydb = ee()->load->database('mydatabase', TRUE);
```

By setting the second parameter to TRUE the function will return the database object.

and then run a query like:

```
$query = $mydb->select('*')->from('tableName')->get();
```

UPDATE:

To set the database prefix to use in the query use:

```
ee()->db->set_dbprefix('myprefix');
```

Comment: Thanks Pete! It's actually the same database, merely a non "exp_" prefixed table. Would this still work?

Comment: Umm, I don't see why not. Just set the database to EE's database. Are you sure ee()->db->set_dbprefix doesn't work? That would be the way to do it I guess.

Comment: set_dbprefix gives me:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::set_dbprefix()

Comment: That's either because you need to call in on the DB object `$mydb` or because EllisLab made the wonderful (being sarcastic) choice to maintain their own fork of Code Igniter instead of mirroring the open source, constantly updated version.